# select column from view getting error attribute or element value is larger than specified in type in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, view, oracle19c

I am using Oracle 19c, and when attempting to select all columns from a view called `AAA_BBB_CCCCC_DDDD_U_1A_1A_U_1A_1A_1A`, I encounter the error

> ORA-22814: attribute or element value is larger than specified in
> type.

The SQL I used is:

```sql
select * from AAA_BBB_CCCCC_DDDD_U_1A_1A_U_1A_1A_1A;
```

However, when I use the same approach to select from another view, it succeeds:

```sql
select * from AAA_BBB_CCCCC_DDDD_U0_U_1A;
```

And the structure of the two tables are as following, the type of `obj1` of `AAA_BBB_CCCCC_DDDD_U_1A_1A_U_1A_1A_1A`  is a customized type called `MY_TYP1` , and the customized type also contains another customized type called `MY_TYP2`, which has a similar structure as `MY_TYP1` and also contains and other customized type `MY_TYP3`.

```sql
CREATE VIEW AAA_BBB_CCCCC_DDDD_U0_U_1A (
    col1 VARCHAR2(200),
    col2 VARCHAR2(200),
    col3 VARCHAR2(200),
    col4 VARCHAR2(4000)
);

CREATE type MY_TYP1  as object (
col4 VARCHAR2(200),
col5 VARCHAR2(200),
type_col MY_TYP2 
);

CREATE VIEW AAA_BBB_CCCCC_DDDD_U_1A_1A_U_1A_1A_1A (
    obj1 MY_TYP1,
    col1 VARCHAR2(200),
    col2 VARCHAR2(200),
    col3 VARCHAR2(200)
);
```

I'd like to ask if there's a length limit on the name of the view in Oracle, or if there might be other reasons causing this error. Additionally, both views have similar structures and both are empty. I wonder why the error occurs with one view and not the other. Any insights or suggestions for resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Your assumption on what is causing the error is almost certainly wrong; however, you have not shared the `CREATE VIEW` statements nor the `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE TYPE` statements for the underlying tables and types your view is using so providing anything more than a theoretical answer is very difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've add the structure of the view and type.

Comment: A `CREATE VIEW` statement is normally `CREATE VIEW view_name (optional_column_list) AS SELECT ...`; your statements look like `CREATE TABLE` statements as they are syntactically invalid as `CREATE VIEW` statements because they do not `SELECT` from anything. Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with the correct `CREATE` statements that allow us to replicate the issue as your recent edit does not.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is nothing to do with the length of the identifiers and is all to do with the size of the data-types you are using in the table and in whatever type your view is using.

---

Let us assume that you have the collection type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE varchar2_table AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(3);
```

And the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (data VARCHAR2(4));

INSERT INTO table_name (data)
SELECT RPAD('X', LEVEL, 'X') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4;
```

Then if you try to `COLLECT` the values from the table and then `CAST` them into a collection:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   TABLE(
         (SELECT CAST(
                   COLLECT(
                     data
                     ORDER BY data
                   ) AS varchar2_table
                 )
          FROM   table_name
          WHERE  LENGTH(data) <= 3)
       );
```

Then you get the error:

> ```
> ORA-22814: attribute or element value is larger than specified in type
> ```

Because you are trying to fit `VARCHAR2(4)` values into collection that only holds `VARCHAR2(3)` data (even though we have restricted the size of the values to only those that will fit into `VARCHAR2(3)`).

We can fix it by adding another `CAST` to ensure that the values are seen as `VARCHAR2(3)` (and not `VARCHAR2(4)`):

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   TABLE(
         (SELECT CAST(
                   COLLECT(
                     CAST(data AS VARCHAR2(3))
                     ORDER BY data
                   ) AS varchar2_table
                 )
          FROM   table_name
          WHERE  LENGTH(data) <= 3)
       );
```

Then the output is:

| COLUMN_VALUE |
| --- |
| X |
| XX |
| XXX |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oWMJeyiJ)